# Can I update my app id on both Play Store and App Store after beta track?

Tags: google-play-services, app-store-connect, bundle-identifier

I currently have a beta application on both the Play Store and App Store. As bundle IDs are conventionally named as tld.domainname.appname, I would like to change my bundle ID due to having to change the name for legal reasons.

Can I change the bundle ID on both Play Store and App Store while allowing current users of the app to update once the bundle ID has changed.

Answer (score 0):

No, package ID and bundle ID are used to identify apps and updates. Once you change them, you will need to setup new apps and the users of the existing apps won't be able to update their existing apps.

The bundle ID for iOS is usually not customer facing. The package ID for Android is used for your app's store link, so you might want to carefully choose a "good" package name. (e.g. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gm --> com.google.android.gm is the package name of the official Gmail app)